# Concatenating numpy arrays and getting desired shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

Let's say I have an numpy array a = [1,2,3,4,5] and another numpy array b = [6,7,8,9,10]. How do I concatenate the arrays and create a numpy array of shape (5,2). I tried both np.row_stack and np.vstack (which do the same thing), but that only results in an np array of shape (2,5). How would I avoid this and get the desired concatenation?

Than you!

Comment: `np.vstack((a, b)).T`

Comment: could also just use array function `np.array([a,b]).T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.vstack` is the way to go, you just need an added transposition step afterwards.

```
c = np.vstack((a, b)).T
print(c)    
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])

print(c.shape)
(5, 2)
```

---

As [djk47463 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028710/concatenating-numpy-arrays-and-getting-desired-shape/46028722#comment79017500_46028710), you can also use the `np.array` constructor (*will delete if they decide to post*):

```
c = np.array([a,b]).T
print(c) 
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

Comment: Very similar to your answer, hoped you would add it :)

Answer (score 2):

Newish `np.stack` gives more control over the new axis:

```
In [37]: a = [1,2,3,4,5]
In [38]: b = [6,7,8,9,10]
In [39]: np.stack((a,b), axis=1)
Out[39]: 
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
In [40]: _.shape
Out[40]: (5, 2)
```

With the default `axis=0`, it behaves like `np.array`, producing a (2,5) array.

`vstack` docs notes:

> This function continues to be supported for backward compatibility, but
>   you should prefer `np.concatenate` or `np.stack`. The `np.stack`
>   function was added in NumPy 1.10.

I think that's overstating the case, but still, `stack` is one of my favorite new functions.  I also recommend looking at the Python code for functions like this.  Most end up using `concatenate` after fiddling with the dimensions of the inputs.